# Поведение ассоциативной карты или TreeMap в Java

Tags: java, коллекции

Что будет если в `TreeMap` запросить значение по несуществующему ключу. Сработает исключение или вернёт `null`

Comment: Как и в обычной хэшмапе вернет null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
System.out.println(map.get("Hello")); 
//На консоль выведит null
```